# Creating a SipStack from a SipFactory

Tags: java, sip, jain-sip

I'm trying to create a `sipStack` out of a `sipFactory` using this code:

```
this.sipFactory = SipFactory.getInstance();
this.sipFactory.setPathName("gov.nist");
// Create and set the SIP stack properties.
this.properties = new Properties();
this.properties.setProperty("javax.sip.STACK_NAME", "stack");
// Create the SIP stack.
this.sipStack = this.sipFactory.createSipStack(this.properties);
```

However I get an exeception that "SipStackImpl" can not be instantiated and I should check if the path name was set, even though I do have that class which implements the SipStack interface in the same package.

What am I missing? How should I create the sip stack?

Answer (score 0):

You can check example code from https://github.com/Mobicents/jain-sip/blob/master/src/examples/simplecallsetup/Shootme.java#L264